# Full Screen Notification in Android

Tags: android, firebase, performance, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am back with a new problem.
Now, I am facing a problem is that I am creating an app that runs as foreground using Foreground Services. Now I want the app to start (launch) a new activity or fragment when the app receives an FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) notification. I have followed this link :[please check this link](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive#java) and then I am confused how to integrate the "incoming call intent(see the link example..please)" into the foreground service. Please tell me. I am literally stuck for days now and could not find a solution that could explain me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

it will trigger only when you/user click on Notification